# Testing Series $ \sum\limits_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n + 2\cos(\alpha n)}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a problem which is related to testing the divergence or convergence for the sum of a series. For more details:
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n + 2\cos(\alpha n)}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
To solve this problem, I think that we need to separate $u_{n}$ into two halves, one alternating series and the other. In general, I find it hard to deal with $\ln(n)$ and $\cos(n)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ because I can not use limits or Taylor for it.

Comment: Use `\cos` `\ln` etc. with a backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n + 2\cos(\alpha n)}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|\leq 
\frac{3}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
for $n\geq 3$. Now, 
$f(x)=\frac{3}{x(\ln x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ is positive and decreasing on $[3,\infty)$, and 
$$\int_3^\infty f(x)dx=\int_3^\infty \frac{3}{x(\ln x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx=\left.-\frac{6}{(\ln x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right|_{3}^\infty<\infty.$$
By [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^\infty \left|\frac{(-1)^n + 2\cos(\alpha n)}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right|$ converges. 
Therefore, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n + 2\cos(\alpha n)}{n(\ln(n))^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ converges absolutely, hence is convergent.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to take the generalized integral from $3$ to $\infty$? Is it used to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} U_n = 0$?

Comment: I think you don't know what integral test is. Look at the link in the answer I posted.